# How can I store MIDI SysEx from hardware synthesizers on my computer?

Tags: midi, synthesizer

I have a couple of hardware synthesizers and I understand that one of their features is to transmit their current settings (and all of their preset settings) by sending them out as MIDI SysEx data. I understand it's possible to store these dumps on a computer, but I'm not sure how this is done. Does it require vendor-specific software for each device, or is there a general solution? What does the workflow look like?

It would be great to make backups of my synth's settings, so that I can try editing them without fear of losing previous settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sysex Librarian](http://www.snoize.com/SysExLibrarian/) will work for you if you're on a Mac. I've successfully used this with my Ensoniq VFXsd and SD-1, both of which are quite finicky about receiving SysEx.

Answer (score 2):

I use [MIDI-Ox](http://www.midiox.com/) for this.

If you go into the SysEx window, there is an option for receiving a dump and sending it.

1. Click View->SysEx
2. Click SysEx->Receive Manual Dump

Nothing vendor-specific needed.  You don't need to interpret the data... just store it and play it back.